# Bayes theorem example

Tags: probability

For the first question I get a very small probability 3.55%. I use bayes theorem to calculate it, is it correct? It seems a bit small to me.

Medical testing
Let us imagine that it is discovered that eating chocolate improves ones maths skills; in fact let us assume the improvement
was so drastic as to be considered an unnatural advantage and the eating of chocolate became considered
cheating at UCT. However, let’s also assume that some students simply could not give up this habit and that say
women were less likely to give the habit up. Let’s say that 1 in 20 men on campus continued to eat chocolate while
1 in 4 women remained chocolate eaters. Now imagine that we mandated tests for chocolate consumption before
exams. If our test has a false positive rate of 7% and a false negative rate 10%.

1. What is the probability that Chaim (a male student) does indeed eat chocolate given that he has tested positive
   as a chocolate eater?
2. What is the probability that Ntombi (a female student) does not eat chocolate given that she has tested negative
   as a chocolate eater?
3. Given these numbers is this a good test for this disease? Explain your answer.

Comment: That is the point of the question, to emphasize that Bayes theorem contradicts our intuition in this kind of situation.

Comment: Is my answer correct? I have realized that probability and intuition are far apart